# theorem relating the genus of a surface to the Euler characteristic

Tags: surfaces, low-dimensional-topology

One of the most basic facts of the theory of surfaces is
$$ \chi = 2-2g $$
where
$$ \chi \triangleq V - E + F $$
for orientables surfaces.

Does this result have a name?

I am also after a proof or a reference to one.

Comment: This result appears as an example in [Hatcher's Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf) chapter 2 on page 146 (available free on the cornell website).

Comment: Apparently this relationship is known as the [Poincaré formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincareFormula.html)